# Filter criteria date and granularity

Tags: 7, views

In my view I filtered for date "greater than now" and in the settings I put granularity "day".

I can see the 3 events correctly, but they are grouped by "month" and not in chronological order though.

Is there any option I can't find by myself to view the events in chronological order?

I sorted by date ASC

This is the export display:
https://kopy.io/DRwkf

This is the export of all the view:
https://kopy.io/KJsM0

[image: view block]

[image: filter criteria]

[image: extra settings]

[image: sort criteria]

Comment: Can you export the view and post it here?

Comment: I add the exports :)

Comment: I updated my answer, please check

Answer (score 0):

In your views sort settings, make sure your Date sort is the first one, because it seems that there is another sort by entity title applied first

---

## UPDATE

After checking the view export:

```
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['granularity'] = 'month';
```

You are sorting the results using "Post Date" of the node, not the date field, you should remove this and add the date field instead

Comment: I have only one sort :(

Comment: Is this Drupal 7 or 8?

Comment: Drupal 7 installed

Comment: If you only have one Sort criteria (node title), you can add a new Sort criteria `Date - start date` and rearrange them so that the Date one comes first, or you can even remove the Title sort. Filters and Sorting are separate things, Filter criteria doesn't affect the Sort criteria.

Comment: As in the pic, I added only one sort criteria by date ASC

Comment: the post date sort is in another display. The problem is the "grouped by month" that has no reason to exist in the "prossimi eventi" display

Comment: I found it, I was in "Format->Settings" a group by date coming from another display...Anyway thanks for making my neurons work :)